# How to select distinct records when using Join?

Tags: mysql, database, string, join, group-by

I got 3 tables whose structure is like this:

```
//postsTable
// pid, userID, parentID, title, date

//userTable
// userID, username, loginDate

//tagTable
// id, pid, tag
```

When a new post is made, user can enter multiple tags, and each tag is stored in a separate row  in tagTable.

Suppose user entered 3 tags.

Then, one row goes in postTable, and 3 rows go in tagTable

When I am selecting, I am using this query:

```
select p.*, c.*, t.* 
from postTable as p 
join userTable as c 
on p.userID = c.userID 
join tagTable as t 
on p.pid = t.pid
where p.parentID='0' 
order by p.date desc limit 10
```

I was hoping this will only select one record from postTable, and one out of 3 tags entered from tagTable and then it will skip to next row in postTable, ignoring the other 2 tags for the same post...

But its selecting 3 records, all duplicate, except the values for t.*

Basically, here is what I want.

select the post from postTable, and select one tag from tagTable and then skip to next row in postTable, ignore left out 2 tags from tagTable for the already selected post.

Something like distinct( p.pid ), c.userID, c.username, t.tag

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You use group by but you have to add something like MIN(Ttag) or if you want all tags use GROUP_CONCAT. The rest that us equal and not in the Grou By , you can use MIN but for tag you have to select  one from these https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: Its not working. I replaced "t.*" with group_concat( t.tag ) and then just after "order by p.date, I added this "group by p.pid", now I get a mysql error saying, "check mysql manual for the right syntax to use near 'group by p.pid"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than picking a random tag out of those available for the post, a sensible option would be to use aggregation and `group_concat()`. This will give you one record per post, along with a comma-separated list of the associated tags:

```
select
    p.pid, 
    p.userID,
    p.parentID,
    p.title,
    p.date,
    u.userID,
    u.username,
    u.loginDate,
    group_concat(t.tag order by t.tag) tags
from 
    postTable as p 
    inner join userTable as u on on p.userID = u.userID 
    inner join tagTable as t on p.pid = t.pid 
where p.parentID = '0'
group by
    p.pid, 
    p.userID,
    p.parentID,
    p.title,
    p.date,
    u.userID,
    u.username,
    u.loginDate
order by p.date
limit 10
```

Comment: This works, but I have one more question. The index on postTable are as follows INDEX( userID, parentID ). Is this query following that index? I asked because parentID='0' is coming at the end after tagTable is joined.

Comment: @SumitKumar: given the `join` and `where` conditions, I would assume that MySQL would use that index. But the only way to be sure is to check the execution plan of the query.

Comment: ok. Thankyou for the help. This is great. I am just learning to use join statements, was using the old method till now, putting everything in where clause... Your solution works :)